# Network on main thread exception even on new thread

Tags: android

I am getting this network on main thread exception, even though I am running a new thread. Any idea what's going wrong here ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final EditText txturl=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtedit);
    Button btngo=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btngo);
    final WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    btngo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Thread t=new Thread(new  Runnable() 
            {

                public void run() 
                {

                    try 
                    {
                        InputStream in=OpenHttpConnection("http://google.com");
                        byte [] buffer = new byte[10000];
                        in.read(buffer);

                        final String s=new String(buffer);

                        wv.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                wv.loadData(s, "text/html", "utf-8");

                            }
                        }) ;



                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

             t.run();

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection (String urlString) throws IOException
{
    URL url=new URL(urlString);
    InputStream in=null;
    int response=-1;

    URLConnection uc=url.openConnection();

    if(!(uc instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an http connection");

    HttpURLConnection httpCon=(HttpURLConnection) uc;

    httpCon.connect();

    response=httpCon.getResponseCode();
    if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        in=httpCon.getInputStream();

    return in;



}
}
```

Comment: use AsyncTask instead of thread , could solve ur issue

Comment: As @Richa says, use an `AsyncTask`. If you really want to use a `Thread` try using `start()` instead of `run()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Please search before asking a question like this. It has been asked already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`run()` executes the method on the current (main) thread, rather than `start()`, which runs the `run` method on a new thread.

Comment: Can you please provide any documentation link for more deep view regarding this?

Comment: @RaviBhatt - from [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html): "the `start()` method must be called to actually execute the new Thread."

Answer (score 1):

As posted earlier the run thread executes on the main thread and as per the new android apis, executing IO operations or network operations on the main thread will throw this error. Hence it is required that you perform the network call in an async task and on post execute method return or update the GUI.